# Convert from long to Timestamp for Insert into DB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Goal:
Read data from a JSON file where timestamp is a long type, and insert into a table that has a Timestamp type. The problem is that I don't know how to convert the long type to a Timestamp type for the insert.

Input File Sample:

```
    {"sensor_id":"sensor1","reading_time":1549533263587,"notes":"My Notes for 
    Sensor1","temperature":24.11,"humidity":42.90}
```

I want to read this, create a Bean from it, and insert into a table. Here is my Bean Definition:

```
public class DummyBean {

    private String sensor_id;
    private String notes;
    private Timestamp reading_time;
    private double temperature;
    private double humidity;
```

Here is the table I want to insert into:

```
    create table dummy (
    id serial not null primary key,
    sensor_id   varchar(40),
    notes   varchar(40),
    reading_time    timestamp with time zone default (current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'),
    temperature   decimal(15,2),
    humidity      decimal(15,2)
    );
```

Here is my Spark app to read the JSON file and do the insert (append)

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("SparkJDBC2")
                .getOrCreate();

        // Java Bean used to apply schema to JSON Data
        Encoder<DummyBean> dummyEncoder = Encoders.bean(DummyBean.class);

        // Read JSON file to DataSet
        String jsonPath = "input/dummy.json";
        Dataset<DummyBean> readings = spark.read().json(jsonPath).as(dummyEncoder);

        // Diagnostics and Sink
        readings.printSchema();
        readings.show();


        // Write to JDBC Sink
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:5432/mydb";
        String table = "dummy";
        Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
        connectionProperties.setProperty("user", "foo");
        connectionProperties.setProperty("password", "bar");
        readings.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, table, connectionProperties);
```

Output and Error Message:

```
root
 |-- humidity: double (nullable = true)
 |-- notes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- reading_time: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- temperature: double (nullable = true)

+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|humidity|               notes| reading_time|sensor_id|temperature|
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|    42.9|My Notes for Sensor1|1549533263587|  sensor1|      24.11|
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Column "reading_time" not found in schema Some(StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,false), StructField(sensor_id,StringType,true), StructField(notes,StringType,true), StructField(temperature,DecimalType(15,2),true), StructField(humidity,DecimalType(15,2),true)));
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$6.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$6.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:147)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$4.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:146)
```

Comment: can you check if the table -"dummy" is having the reading_time column in postgres console ?.

Answer (score 0):

The exception in your post says "reading_time" column not found.. so please cross check if the table is having the required column in the db end. Also, the timestamp is coming in milli seconds, so you need to divide that by 1000 before applying the to_timestamp() function, otherwise you'll get a weird date.

I'm able to replicate below and convert the reading_time.

```
scala> val readings = Seq((42.9,"My Notes for Sensor1",1549533263587L,"sensor1",24.11)).toDF("humidity","notes","reading_time","sensor_id","temperature")
readings: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [humidity: double, notes: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> readings.printSchema();
root
 |-- humidity: double (nullable = false)
 |-- notes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- reading_time: long (nullable = false)
 |-- sensor_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- temperature: double (nullable = false)


scala> readings.show(false)
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|humidity|notes               |reading_time |sensor_id|temperature|
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|42.9    |My Notes for Sensor1|1549533263587|sensor1  |24.11      |
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+


scala>  readings.withColumn("ts", to_timestamp('reading_time/1000)).show(false)
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+
|humidity|notes               |reading_time |sensor_id|temperature|ts                     |
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+
|42.9    |My Notes for Sensor1|1549533263587|sensor1  |24.11      |2019-02-07 04:54:23.587|
+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Yes the table was missing the column so I fixed that.
This is what solved it (Java version)

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp;

...
Dataset<Row>  readingsRow = readings.withColumn("reading_time", to_timestamp(col("reading_time").$div(1000L)));

// Write to JDBC Sink
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:5432/mydb";
String table = "dummy";
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
connectionProperties.setProperty("user", "foo");
connectionProperties.setProperty("password", "bar");
readingsRow.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, table, connectionProperties);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your date is String you can use

```
String readtime = obj.getString("reading_time");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); //Z for time zone
Date reading_time = sdf.parse(readtime);
```

or use

```
new Date(json.getLong(milliseconds))
```

if it is long